# View base model importance/coeffecients for h2o stacked ensembles/automl

Tags: python, h2o

How do I see the coefficients or importance of the various base models in an stacked ensemble in h2o?  For example if I have a GBM, GLM, and RF how do I know how important each one is in the stacking?  Is this possible?

For example using the python code... here....

http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/stacked-ensembles.html

Answer (score 4):

The Stacked Ensemble algorithm in H2O uses GLM as the metalearning algorithm, so you can interpret the magnitude of the coefficients of the GLM metalearner as the "importance" of each base learner in making a prediction in the ensemble.

In the simple [example](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/stacked-ensembles.html#example) that's in the Stacked Ensemble documentation, we train a 2-model (GBM, RF) ensemble.  This is how you'd inspect the coefficients of the metalearner GLM in Python:

```
import h2o
from h2o.estimators.random_forest import H2ORandomForestEstimator
from h2o.estimators.gbm import H2OGradientBoostingEstimator
from h2o.estimators.stackedensemble import H2OStackedEnsembleEstimator
h2o.init()

# Import a sample binary outcome train/test set into H2O
train = h2o.import_file("https://s3.amazonaws.com/erin-data/higgs/higgs_train_10k.csv")
test = h2o.import_file("https://s3.amazonaws.com/erin-data/higgs/higgs_test_5k.csv")

# Identify predictors and response
x = train.columns
y = "response"
x.remove(y)

# For binary classification, response should be a factor
train[y] = train[y].asfactor()
test[y] = test[y].asfactor()

# Number of CV folds (to generate level-one data for stacking)
nfolds = 5

# Generate a 2-model ensemble (GBM + RF)

# Train and cross-validate a GBM
my_gbm = H2OGradientBoostingEstimator(distribution="bernoulli",
                                      ntrees=10,
                                      max_depth=3,
                                      min_rows=2,
                                      learn_rate=0.2,
                                      nfolds=nfolds,
                                      fold_assignment="Modulo",
                                      keep_cross_validation_predictions=True,
                                      seed=1)
my_gbm.train(x=x, y=y, training_frame=train)

# Train and cross-validate a RF
my_rf = H2ORandomForestEstimator(ntrees=50,
                                 nfolds=nfolds,
                                 fold_assignment="Modulo",
                                 keep_cross_validation_predictions=True,
                                 seed=1)
my_rf.train(x=x, y=y, training_frame=train)


# Train a stacked ensemble using the GBM and RF above
ensemble = H2OStackedEnsembleEstimator(base_models=[my_gbm.model_id, my_rf.model_id])
ensemble.train(x=x, y=y, training_frame=train)

# Grab the metalearner GLM fit & print normalized coefficients
metafit = h2o.get_model(ensemble.metalearner()['name'])
metafit.coef_norm()
```

This prints the following:

```
{u'DRF_model_python_1502159734743_250': 0.6967886117663271,
 u'GBM_model_python_1502159734743_1': 0.48518914691349374,
 u'Intercept': 0.1466358030144971}
```

So in this case, the Random Forest's predictions are contributing to the ensemble prediction more than the GBM.

If you evaluate the base models on a test set, you can see that the Random Forest performs slightly better than the GBM, so it makes sense that the ensemble would prefer RF predictions slightly more than GBM (although there is not always a straight-forward 1-1 correspondence between test set performance and metalearner variable importance like this).

```
my_gbm.model_performance(test).auc()  # 0.7522498803447679
my_rf.model_performance(test).auc() # 0.7698039263004212
```

There are plans to [expose the metalearner as an argument](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-3743?filter=19301) so that the user can use any of H2O's supervised ML algos as a metalearner in the future, and in that case, you could look at the variable importance of the algorithm to get the same information since all the H2O algorithms compute variable importance.